# Default parameters using Blowfish in TCL

Tags: java, encryption, tcl, blowfish

Our production environment (TCL) are storing some data in the DB with blowfish encryption and I'm trying to do the same from Java for our test automation.

I fail to get encrypt/decrypt with same result and I suspect the standard settings for Blowfish in TCL are different from Java. Anyone now what the default settings are for Blowfish in TCL so I can reproduce the same code in Java?

I'm not that good in TCL but this is the code executing the encryption

```
return [blowfish encrypt -hex $CFG(secretkey) -bin $data]
```

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Some code? What mode of operation does your production enviroment use? The only problem i can imagine at the moment.

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by "Mode of Operation"?. I have tried with both ECB and CBC from my Java code

Comment: That is not the blowfish module from tcllib isn't it? What about the Java source? Are you sure the secret key is correct? Sometimes erros come from the simple things.

Comment: Yeah, I have run the TCL code my self with the same secret key and data to be sure of the output and correct data. I have somewhat limited access to the developers as they are an external partner.. I'm starting to suspect I need the correct IV for CBC but can't see anywhere that being set in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the blowfish code from Tcllib? If so, what exactly it is doing is documented [on the manual page](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/blowfish.html). In short, you really ought to specify the mode (ECB or CBC) and initialization vector when initializing the cypher; try specifying it and seeing whether it gives the same results. If so, you've got the settings you need to replicate from the other side.

Also, from that page:

> The *-mode* and *-dir* options are optional and default to cbc mode and encrypt respectively. The initialization vector *-iv* takes an 8 byte binary argument which defaults to 8 zeros. See [MODES OF OPERATION](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/blowfish.html#SECTid81c6c78) for more about available modes and their uses.